# google earth client/plugin, simultaneously play a tour over 3 computers

Tags: javascript, google-earth, google-earth-plugin

Hello im synchronising view of 3 computer with Google earth client and also plugin, is there a way to synchronise the play tour on all 3 machines? either with client, plugin or both?

Comment: I think it would be possible to have a situation of 1 master and numerous slaves using the plugin. Have a look at this page on an example of controlling the view of one plug-in instance from another (these are on same page but I am sure it would be able to be sent across the internet to another) - http://earth-api-utility-library.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/extensions/examples/vantage-view.html

Comment: Thanks for the help =) that code from what i can see is just calling a new instance of Google earth plguin, the hard part is to get it to communicate over the network

Comment: then why don't you look into loading your KML files via NetworkLinks ......

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a technology such as websockets. We are using Atmostphere (https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere) for synchronizing the content of the Plugin.
I think you can use http://socket.io/ in the server I think it's easier to use than Atmosphere